# Fast way to implement Cosine similarities on large Sparse Matrices in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity

I have a large sparse matrix (300,000 X 60,000) and trying to calculate pairwise similarity between users. The final similarity matrix will be (300,000 X 300,000). I have tried using `cosSparse` from `"qlcMatrix"`  and `cosine` from `"coop"` but none of them seems to be working efficiently with respect to time. Is there a way to implement or any packages that have already implemented the same or should I move to other programming languages?

Comment: what doesn't work? does it not like the input form, or take too long or ... ?? How much ram have you got?

Comment: I have updated my question. Input form is okay. My concern is with respect to time. I tried with 100,000 X 100,000 and it's still running (almost 45 minutes now). I have enough ram since I am using University cluster.

Comment: How sparse us the matrix? How many actual similarities out of 9e10 need to be calculated? You might need to parallelize this.

Comment: Since the similarity file is going to be very big, I am calculating similarities individually and writing them to HDF files. I understand this isn't the solution I am looking for but for now, it's working fine. I will close the question if someone suggest me a better solution.

Comment: Do you need all similarities or only largest?

Comment: It would be good if I can have all, else I am okay with fixing a threshold and saving the similarities that are only greater than say 0.3